# What .Net object corresponds to an IronRuby hash

Tags: hash, ironruby

I want to call a C# method from an IronRuby script that results in a Ruby hash. I tried Dictionary but that stays as is.

```
public Dictionary<string, string> GetHash()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> hash = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    hash.Add("a", "1");
    hash.Add("b", "2");
    return hash;
}
```

I'd like to be able to use it in my IronRuby script as a hash

```
myHash = scopeObj.GetHash()
myHash.each{ |k,v|
    print("#{k}=#{v}")
}
```

The results of which are:

```
 [a, 1]=
 [b, 2]=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work like that since the items in a .NET dictionary are KeyValuePair instances.

You can workaround that pretty easily, with a single line of conversion code:

```
d = scopeObj.get_hash
h = Hash[*d.collect { |x| [x.key,x.value] }.flatten]
h.each { |k,v| puts k,v }
```